# Does anyone know how to use/perform this card and number trick?

Tags: magic

I have these green cards which used to go to some magic trick but I no longer have the instructions. Does anyone know how the performance goes?

[image]

Comment: If it is a dupe, the numbers are different. I would like to see how it plays out to see if it is performed the same way..

Comment: @JasonV The numbers are almost the same, this one just goes up to 63, while that other one stopped at 60.

Comment: The only difference I see in this one vs the linked question is that the important numbers are at the top right, and you could also seem to be more amazing to ask for the card letters at the top left.  So if they told you cards A, D, and F, a little bit of mental math gives you 41.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask a volunteer/victim to pick a number between 1 and 63. Then they tell you the letter of any papers on which they see their number. From that, you tell them their number almost immediately.

How it works

> Each card shows numbers with a "1" in a certain digits place in binary. For example, any number with a "1" in the "ones" place [meaning the number is odd] is on card A. Any number with a "1" in the "thirty-twos" place [meaning >+32] is on card F.
>
> So you just make a number from that. To do it quickly, add up the numbers of each place based on letters: A=1, B=2, C=4, D=8, E=16, F=32
>
> Just add up the values of the letters they say, and that's their number!

Boom!

Comment: @APrough thanks, that looks a lot more professional, now!